# VSCode: How to split editor using same shortkeys as Sublime Text

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Sublime Text I can use the following shortkeys:

```
ALT+SHIFT+2 : create two columns
ALT+SHIFT+3 : create three columns
...
```

I want to be able to do the exact same thing in VSCode (without downloading the Sublime Text keybinding since I want the rest to stay the same)

Comment: do you actually want to split the current editor into 2 or 3 columns with that file in each column, or do you just want to create 2 or 3 columns that you then open different files in?

Comment: I want to do the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for `columns` within the "Keyboard Shortcuts" editor, you wil see these options:

`workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoColumns`

`workbench.action.editorLayoutThreeColumns`

They are unbound to any keyboard shortcut by default.  Click the plus sign to the left of each of these commands in turn and you will get a dialog box where you can enter your chosen keybinding for each and you are done.

[image: demo]

Comment: It worked !!! Btw, is the limit " ThreeColumns " ? Because I don't see " FourColumns " (dont need more than three, but just good to know)

Comment: It looks like three is the maximum via one command.  But you could open three and then split one of those empty editors into another empty editor via `Ctrl+\\` to get a fourth, etc.